# Django Bleach with CKeditor?

Tags: python, django, bleach

Good morning,
have you already configured Django Bleach for CKEDITOR?
Actually I'm using a form with Django. And I use CKEDITOR to be able to write.
But is there a configuration to use Django Bleach with?
Because in my template I use |safe.

THANKS

I want to safe the data send with ckeditor.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Message")
```

forms.py

```
class IdeaCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField(widget=ReCaptchaV2Checkbox)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ["content"]
```

views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = IdeaCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = user
            form.instance.idea = idea
            form.save()
            return redirect(idea)
    else:
        form = IdeaCommentForm()
```

hrml

```
<div class="card-body">

    <p class="card-text">{{ comment.content|safe }}</p>

  </div>
```

thks !